# XCode not importing OS X crash log

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have a crash log for my app sent to me by a tester. According to the documentation I should be able to drop this into the 'Device Logs' section of the Library in the Organizer (or use the 'Import' button at the bottom of the window).

Unfortunately both does nothing. No error, no warning, no import.

My .crash file was created by hand by copying the content of an email so maybe the formatting is incorrect, comparing it to other crash files it seems correct though.

I have the build the crash log refers to in my archive also, as I know this is important for symbols to show up.

Any idea how I can debug this? This is using Xcode 4.4.1

Comment: Have you tried drag/drop other crash files? Does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I broke down and used one of my support credits with Apple to try and get to the bottom of this.

The bottom line is quite simple. As of now (Xcode 4.6), OS X crash logs cannot be imported into Xcode. Only iOS ones.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I see you put a bounty on the question but the answer is right there :)

Comment: @uchuugaka stack overflow doesn't enforce anyone else's NDA (has been discussed often) and I haven't revealed any company secrets so I doubt apple cares either.

Comment: But it's good to call out. I wouldn't do business with anyone who is incapable of honoring a very simple legal agreement. Would you?

Comment: @uchuugaka I wouldn't do business with someone who jumps through hoops just because of some arcane legal requirement. Anybody running into this problem has access to Xcode 5, and it is valuable to the community to know that the bug still exists. Apple's pending patent filings and weird edge cases of US patent law (the most likely reason for the NDA) are not going to suffer because we discuss a bug in Xcode 5.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your disregard for legal agreements and contractual obligations and licenses.

Comment: I suppose it would be ok if Apple decided to disclose your information or not pay you for App Store sales? You can't just choose to follow the bits you like and expect it to go well.

Answer (score 9):

I experienced the same issue when I tried to import crash logs generated by PLCrashReporter. Then I noticed that Incident identifier and CrashReporter key fields in the crash reports are populated with "[TODO]" string instead of correct values. I replaced incident identifiers with arbitrary UUIDs and crash reporter key with UDID of one of my devices, and after that XCode was able to import the reports. I use XCode 4.5

Comment: Great!! , I could imported, actually I didn´t write any number in Incident Identifier and CrashReporter Key. The unique problem is that it didn´t show with the re-Symbolicate.

Thanksssss

Comment: Making this change allowed me to get the files into Xcode.  Thanks!  (Though they still don't symbolicate...)

Comment: @Arkaaito , make sure that XCode has a dSYM file for the application which had crashed. An archive which contains _exactly_ the same version that crashed should appear in Organizer / Archives section, otherwise XCode will not have enough information to symbolicate your crash log.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect an Xcode bug.
I have the same problem with Xcode 4.4.1. Even tried the latest 4.5.2 developer release.

I used an earlier version of Xcode, and it kinda worked (only importing one crash at a time, required to relaunch Xcode several times, but I managed to do what I needed).

You can download an older version of Xcode [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode).

---

I had *some* success with deleting `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS Device Logs` when Xcode refused to cooperate. Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: @Aliaksei: Good to know. I suggest you post your comment as an answer, to make it more visible to future readers.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not an answer to the original question. This must be related to iOS logs since OS X logs are not supported by Xcode at this time (4.6).